# Onclick remove function jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a website that I'm building and it has 2 jQueries each one with a different function.

The first one is to have sticky headers:

```
var stickyHeaders = (function() {

  var $window = $(window),
    $stickies;

  var load = function(stickies) {

    if (typeof stickies === "object" && stickies instanceof jQuery && stickies.length > 0) {

      $stickies = stickies.each(function() {

        var $thisSticky = $(this).wrap('<div class="followWrap" />');

        $thisSticky
          .data('originalPosition', $thisSticky.offset().top)
          .data('originalHeight', $thisSticky.outerHeight())
          .parent()
          .height($thisSticky.outerHeight());
      });

      $window.off("scroll.stickies").on("scroll.stickies", function() {
        _whenScrolling();
      });
    }
  };

  var _whenScrolling = function() {

    $stickies.each(function(i) {

      var $thisSticky = $(this),
        $stickyPosition = $thisSticky.data('originalPosition');

      if ($stickyPosition <= $window.scrollTop()) {

        var $nextSticky = $stickies.eq(i + 1),
          $nextStickyPosition = $nextSticky.data('originalPosition') - $thisSticky.data('originalHeight');

        $thisSticky.addClass("fixed");

        if ($nextSticky.length > 0 && $thisSticky.offset().top >= $nextStickyPosition) {

          $thisSticky.addClass("absolute").css("top", $nextStickyPosition);
        }

      } else {

        var $prevSticky = $stickies.eq(i - 1);

        $thisSticky.removeClass("fixed");

        if ($prevSticky.length > 0 && $window.scrollTop() <= $thisSticky.data('originalPosition') - $thisSticky.data('originalHeight')) {

          $prevSticky.removeClass("absolute").removeAttr("style");
        }
      }
    });
  };

  return {
    load: load
  };
})();

$(function() {
  stickyHeaders.load($(".followMeBar"));
});
```

And the other one is to increase, decrease the font size:

```
$('#smallerFont').click(function() {
  var htmlFontSize = $('#content p').css("font-size");
  htmlFontSize = parseInt(htmlFontSize, 10);
  if (htmlFontSize > 14) {
    $('#content p').css("font-size", "-=2");
  }
  return false;
});
$('#largerFont').click(function() {
  var htmlFontSize = $('#content p').css("font-size");
  htmlFontSize = parseInt(htmlFontSize, 10);
  if (htmlFontSize < 24) {
    $('#content p').css("font-size", "+=2");
  }
  return false;
});
```

What I want and need is to kill, unload, whatever the first function when I click the link that activates the second one:

```
<a href="#" id="largerFont" class="ml-2">+A</a>
```

This is because sticky headers get all messed up when the font is increased or decreased without refreshing. The objects that stick move out of place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got to a solution.

```
$('#smallerFont').click(function() {
  $("div.chapter_header").removeClass("followMeBar");
  var htmlFontSize = $('#content p').css("font-size");
  htmlFontSize = parseInt(htmlFontSize, 10);
  if (htmlFontSize > 14) {
    $('#content p').css("font-size", "-=2");

  }
  return false;
});
```

Removed the class the first function needed to work